# Why are there extra and unrelated texts below the code block in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, windows-live-writer

I insert some bash codes into a blog using `windows live write` with a code plugin and post it.

However, there are a lot of unrelated texts below the code in the blog. Here is:

```
.csharpcode, .csharpcode pre
{
font-size: small;
color: black;
font-family: consolas, “Courier New”, courier, monospace;
background-color: #ffffff;
/*white-space: pre;*/
}
.csharpcode pre { margin: 0em; }
.csharpcode .rem { color: #008000; }
.csharpcode .kwrd { color: #0000ff; }
.csharpcode .str { color: #006080; }
.csharpcode .op { color: #0000c0; }
.csharpcode .preproc { color: #cc6633; }
.csharpcode .asp { background-color: #ffff00; }
.csharpcode .html { color: #800000; }
.csharpcode .attr { color: #ff0000; }
.csharpcode .alt
{
background-color: #f4f4f4;
width: 100%;
margin: 0em;
}
.csharpcode .lnum { color: #606060; }
```

There is nothing while running the command `grep -R "csharpcode"` under my wordpress. I didn't make any change on wordpress except updating some plugins.

**I remove `WP-Markdown` and everything is fine. Can everyone explain it?**

Comment: It looks like a syntax highlighter is injecting that css via javascript. What sort of scripts do you have running?

Comment: @JesseKernaghan scripts? Did you mean which code plugin I use? [Insert Code for Windows Live Writer](http://insertcode.codeplex.com/releases/view/840)

Comment: @JesseKernaghan  I remove `WP-Markdown` and everything is fine. How can I explain it?

Comment: try going a grep for `csharp.css`. WP-Markdown is injecting it automatically.

Comment: @JesseKernaghan there is an option `Enable Prettify syntax highlighter` under `WP Markdown`. So can I delete `csharp.css` simply?